# Prevent users from stealing password using WireShark and such

Tags: c#, ftp, sftp, wireshark

I have a Windows Forms Application which communicates with an FTP Server everything works flawlessly, except that the user is able to use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/), filter for FTP and easily get full access to my FTP Server. I really need a way to prevent this, but the only idea I could come up with was to use SFTP or FTPS. The problem is that currently I'm using [edtFTPnet free](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/overview.html) and couldn't find any free SFTP or FTPS class to implement on my current code.

What would be the best approaches (free or extremely low cost) to solve this problem?

Comment: even if it's 'encrypted' when you transmit the password, it's still in your application, which anyone can decompile and grab for themselves.

Comment: SharpSSH can do SFTP; but hometoast is very correct about decompiling...

Comment: Didn't know about decompile, should take a look into. See if there is a way to scramble the password.

Comment: @BrunoKlein: You can, but you have to de-crypt it in your program before sending it over the wire. That means, the bad guy also can do it, because after a decompile he knows how your program does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few free SSH libraries: ([SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx), [SSH.Net](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) for example)

The problem is you're relying on someone not looking at the password. Instead, issue your clients their own credentials. Be it, username & passwords per user or issue the client a certificate.

Also, Daniel's advice is sound; make sure that if they DO get the password, there's little to no damage that can be done

Comment: Just took a look at SSH.Net. It provides just sufficiently what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are going the wrong way here.

You don't really have control over the client side, so don't bother trying to secure it.

Instead, secure your server.
Make sure that the account used by your application only has limited rights on the FTP server. For example, you could disallow DIR or constrain him to a certain directory.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but it cannot be implemented, because my application needs to have access to certain directories that the user cannot access, for example. Or even delete files from the FTP.

Comment: Understandable, but the main point is that if your application can access the data, a "bad guy" can too.